# Magento - Mass updating of stock levels fails due to blank spaces in CSV

Tags: magento, csv, whitespace, stock

I am using following code to update stock in Magento 1.7.0.1
After hours of investigation, I have realized that the code works perfectly but my csv is the problem.

Following is where the script is
http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/mass-update-stock-levels-in-magento-fast/

I am using dos program to create csv file and it's creating blank spaces at the end of each line causing the script not to import properly.

"sku","qty","is_in_stock"
"prod1","11","1"

About csv looks correct but it each line has about 25 blank spaces that you don't see.

If I open csv and remove all the spaces, save it and import it using stock.php, everything works great.

DOS program is not able to get rid of those spaces...is there any way to remove it from php script?

Answer (score 0):

For example like this:

```
$sFile = 'my.csv';
$aFile = file($sFile);
foreach ($aFile as $iLine => $sLine) {
    $aFile[$iLine] = trim($sLine);
}
file_put_contents(
    $sFile,
    implode("\n", $aFile),

);
```